# Characterization of Normal Operator by the trace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I want to prove the following exercise:
Given a complex $n$-dimensional vector space with inner product, show that for any linear operator $T$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,..., \lambda_n$ (counted with multiplicity): a) $tr(T^*T)\geqslant \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2$; b) $T$ is normal iff the inequality is an equality.

Comment: Hint: complex square matrices can be unitarily triangularised.